# Правила для определения четных/нечетных с игнорированием определенных блоков

Tags: css, html5

Имеем такую разметку:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо стилизовать классы `list` по принципу четности/нечетности, но игнорируя класс `ignore`, т.е. так:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div> -- нечетный
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div> -- четный
    <div class="ignore">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div> -- нечетный
    <div class="list">...</div> -- четный
</div>
```

Простые `event`/`odd`для `.list:nth-child` не подходят, т.к после `.ignore` отсчет начинается сначала.

Comment: Нельзя такое сделать

Comment: только на  `JS` проставлять доп. классы

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а с чего вы решили, что вопрос связан с JavaScript? Автор ни слова об этом не сказал, так что не нужно ставить метки, которые не имеют отношения к вопросу.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Автор спросил, как это можно сделать. Одно из средств выполнения задачи - это использование JS. Поэтому целесообразно включить эту метку, так как помимо всего прочего кто-то может будет в будущем искать решение этой же задачи на JS.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, а еще эту задачу можно решить на стороне сервера, при генерации HTML. Предлагаете включить метки python, ruby, php, ...? Не нужно выставлять метки, которые не имеют отношения к вопросу. Если автор посчитает нужным, он сам их добавит

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Во-первых, в вопросе не указаны какие-либо ограничения. Во-вторых, для поиска тем важна не только информация в вопросе, а на самом деле часто главнее информация, представленная в ответах, так как она показывает, как можно решить задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант, если не брать за основу классы - использовать [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type), который в принципе аналогичен `:nth-child`, только применяет правило дополнительно привязываясь к тегу(типу), а не всем дочерним элементам. Собственно чтобы этим воспользоваться, все игнорируемые элементы должны быть заключены в тег, отличный от основного тега для подствечиваемых элементов. Например HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="ignore">...</p>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <p class="ignore">...</p>
    <p class="ignore">...</p>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <p class="ignore">...</p>
    <div class="list">...</div>
    <div class="list">...</div>
</div>
```

Стили, где у всех `div.list` цвет будет чередоваться независимо от их позиции в родителе:

```
.list {
    background: red;
}

.list:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: green;
}
```

[Пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wicapatado/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Получается более оптимальный вариант, если опустить факт, что <p> это не блок. С тильдой мы ограничиваемся количеством прописанных в CSS  "~ .list", с яваскриптом, будет все же определенная задержка в исполнении, либо при определенных условиях вообще не отработает.

Answer (score 3):

на css наверное только так

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6tv3qqhd/)

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;        
}

.list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list {
    background: #00f;
}
.list ~ .list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list,
.list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list ~ .list{
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
    <div class="list">Odd</div>
    <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
    <div class="ignore">Ignore.</div>
    <div class="list">Even</div>
    <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
    <div class="list">Odd</div>
    <div class="list">Even</div>
</div>
```

Comment: вау, даже не подумал о таком решении. Круто, жаль не применимо для большинства таблиц

Comment: @korytoff согласен - наверное самым оптимальным решением здесь будет использование js

Comment: Я бы `:first-child` всё-таки прописал... Хотя не, не поможет - тут же тильда... Оригинально.

Answer (score 1):

С JS это можно, например, сделать следующим образом

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html lang = "ru">

<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <title>Odd-even</title>
    <style>
        /* можно было бы использовать специальный стиль для odd-even */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
        <div class="list">Odd</div>
        <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
        <div class="ignore">Ignore.</div>
        <div class="list">Even</div>
        <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
        <div class="list">Odd</div>
        <div class="list">Even</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function changeListStyle() {
            var lists = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
            var odd = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
                var item = lists[i];
                if (odd ^= true) item.style.color = "Red";
                else item.style.color = "blue";
            }
        };

        window.onload = changeListStyle();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```